# Sas how to have 2 byvar in a display

Tags: sas, report, proc, byval

Normally in sas proc report we can use the byvar/byval to have the by category at the top of the display. In my case my display has 2 by categories. And I am not sure how to do that. I can add one using proc report but I don't know how to add 2.

I want my display to be like:

Sex: Male (100)
Treatment: Aspirin (40mg) (N=21)

### column1    column2     column3

Comment: Please show details about what you have tried.  Code and data would help a lot.  If you are using BY statement then you just need list all of the variables in the BY statement.  `by sex treatment;`

Answer (score 0):

Precompute the group size and add that variable to the by grouping. Use inline styling in a single `TITLE` statement, or `TITLE1` `TITLE2` statements.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit (2021);
  do g1=1 to 3;
  do g2=1 to 3;
    do _n_ = 1 to rand('integer', 5);
      pid + 1;
      array c col1-col3;
      do over c; z+1; c=z; end;
      output;
    end;
  end;
  end;
  drop z;
run;

options nodate nonumber nocenter nobyline;
ods escapechar='^';

proc sql;
  create table reportdata as
  select *, count(*) as count from have group by g1, g2 order by g1, g2, col1;

proc report data=reportdata;
  title '#byvar1: #byval1^n#byvar2: #byval2 (n=#byval3)';
  by g1 g2 count;
  columns col1-col3;
  define col1-col3/display;
run;
```

Output:

[image]